# Android Text Menus

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some XML that I am using as an Android text menu.

Here is the XML

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search" android:title="@string/menu_search"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="@string/menu_exit" android:orderInCategory="200" ></item>

 </menu>
```

In inflate the menu using the following code

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

When I am checking for the menu items clicked, I use this.

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemid = item.getItemId();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!" + itemid, itemid).show();
        return true;
    }
```

This is giving me a numeric ID for each menu item pressed. Should I use a case statement to check this and then launch the pages I want to open? Or is there a way for me to link an intent to a menu item ? Its seems like a bit of a waste to be adding this code to each screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use case statment for calling :-

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:

             return true;
              case R.id.menu_setting2:

             return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For using the same menu in different activity do one thing just extends Activity class in your MenuActivity class and in other classes just extends the MenuActivity class Instead of Activity, by doing this their is no need to write same piece of code again and again.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.menulayout);

    }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuxml, menu); 
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

               // pass menu item in cases
        case R.id.menu1:

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,
                        Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent1 );

            break;

                              case R.id.menu2:

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,
                        Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent2 );

            break;

        return true;
    }
}
```

//And here is the other Activity which extends the MenuActivity

```
public class Activity1 extends MenuActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
}
```

}